# Integrating Groovy development into Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, groovy

I am using NetBeans / Java EE combination,
and when doing development, compile-on-save and hot redeploy works very fast on Java source code.  I am trying integrate Groovy into this process.

There is no compile-on-save support for Groovy, and if I just compile the app,
there is no way to hot-deploy it into Glassfish from within NetBeans,
which makes Groovy development in this environment just about impossible.

The only way to redeploy a running app is to re-run it from NetBeans.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to develop Groovy alongside Java in Java EE/NetBeans/GlassFish environment?

Comment: My guess is this is related to the groovy compiler. Ever wondered about trying the `indy` groovy?

Comment: I found this blog: https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/groovy_mojarra but it's from 2008. I am not sure how current this support is and if it's maintained.